# Suggested edit review history doesn't show the edit in context

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review-history

I rejected [this (minor) suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1952992) because it didn't remove OP 'thanks' from the post, no big deal.  Looking at the suggested edit review history now this is not apparent - because the suggestion is rendered in some way relative to the *current* state of the post, rather than the post as it was at the time, and the 'thanks' have subsequently been edited away.  The post is shown with the current tags, rather than the tags at the time the edit was suggested.

When looking at suggested edits reviews after the fact we should see the post as it was at the time, and the suggested edit relative to that.  Ideally the same inline/markdown/side-by-side display options should be available for viewing historical suggestion as when reviewing them in the queue.

Here's the approved suggested edit - revision 2 - in the post history:

[image]

*Only the title was fixed in revision 2. The review history for that suggested edit shows this though:*

[image]

*No sign of the "thanks", even though it was not removed until sometime later in revision 5:*

[image]